# when is a String not a String? when it doesn't have an includes() method?

Tags: javascript, string, coffeescript

I'm trying to write a simple javascript(well coffeescript) test and have something confusing:

```
dclib.appendVarToUrl = (base, k, v) ->
  check base, String
  console.log("base is a:", typeof(base))
  if base.includes("?")
     ... 

// called with
dclib.appendVarToUrl("some/url", "score", 5)
```

gives me:

```
base is a: string
TypeError: Object some/url has no method 'includes'
```

so why would a String not have an .includes() method?
is this coffeescript wrapping an object in a weird way?

Comment: `.includes()` is not a native javascript `String` method

Answer (score 1):

aha, it looks like my browser supports this as an ES6 method, but the node version I'm using doesn't. I was running unit tests on the server whereas the method ran fine on the client.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

> This is an experimental technology, part of the ECMAScript 6 (Harmony) proposal.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) indeed it doesn't. You are probably looking for `.indexOf`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: @dcsan the document you linked to shows you that it's not very well supported

Answer (score 0):

According the the specification [.includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) is part of ECMAScript 6 JavaScript Version. Therefore many platforms still do not support it.

You can replace by `.indexOf()!=-1` which is equivalent and belongs to ECMAScript 1 JavaScript Version. According to the specification [`.indexOf()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) returns -1 when it doesn't find the specific string.

Therefore a) and b) are equivalent

a) ECMAScript 6

```
var str = "Hello world";

if (str.includes("world")){
  return true
}
```

b) ECMAScript 1

```
var str = "Hello world";

if (str.indexOf("world")!==-1){
  return true
}
```